# Show control over other grid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I try to find a way to put my Combobox (UserControl) over another grid, but I can't. I'm tried to use Panel.ZIndex, ClipToBonus but they not working.

My XAML Code

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <RowDefiniton Height="50"/>
     <RowDefiniton/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitons>

  <Grid Background="#1e1e1e" ClipToBonus="false" Panel.ZIndex="10">
     <control:Combobox x:Name="CbType" Width="200" Height="30" Panel.ZIndex="10"/>
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Row="1" Background="#1e1e1e" ClipToBonus="false" Panel.ZIndex="1">
     <control:ViewData x:Name="ViewControl" Width="500" Height="300" Panel.ZIndex="1"/>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I want when Combobox(CbType) drop-down it shows over ViewData(ViewControl).  What way I can do for my problem?

Thank for your attention.

Comment: The popup of the combobox should show over whatever element that is underneath it. How does it currently look like?

Comment: Popup can't be use because I have many layout overlaps. When I use popup it show over all layout.

Comment: Isn' this what you wanted...? How is the template of your custom control defined and why don't you use the built-in one?

Comment: Because I can't make it like my application style and it not have some function I need. So I make new one

Comment: But why can't you use a popup in your template?

Comment: I'm trying to use it. But when I use it all of the element in it is drift away to another location and I can't control it.

Comment: You should provide a [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue when asking a question on SO.

Comment: When using the Popup you should set the `Popup.PlacementTarget` to dock to a specific position in your layout.